# Can I convert numbers to amount of characters in Python

Tags: python

Can I convert a number like 3 into a string that gives me the amount of characters in an input? Like: 3 = ---  and 6 = ------

Comment: I did but I didnt know how to describe it, I thought it would be more complex then I see it actually is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure:

```
def print_dash(n):
    print("-" * n)
```

Output:

```
print_dash(5)
-----
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
n=3
print(n*"-")
# ---
n=6
print(n*"-")
# ------
```

Answer (score 1):

Python has an easy formatting for this kind of questions :

```
print("-" * n)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
n = int(input("Enter your number: "))

print("-" * n)
```